# Iterate over a large list with Asyncio and get url file size for each element

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have a dataframe with 287.000+ file urls at the column df1['Gravação']. I want to get the length of all the files and save into the list tamanho_mb = [ ]

I was able to make the synchronous formula normally, but since the amount of data is very large, I would like to use asyncio to make it faster.

the synchronous approach for this is:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib.request as ur
import requests
import asyncio

df1 = pd.read_csv("report.csv", sep = ';', encoding = 'utf-8')

df1['Gravação'] = ['https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Pic.png', 'https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-File.png', 'https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Photo.png', 'https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Clipart.png'\]

tamanho_mb = [ ]
for i in df1['Gravação']:
    tamanho = ur.urlopen(i)
    tamanho = tamanho.length
    tamanho_mb.append(tamanho)
```

how could i achieve the same result using asyncio?

Comment: can you give report.csv file url to download for test

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

lst = [
    "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Pic.png",
    "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-File.png",
    "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Photo.png",
    "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Clipart.png",
]

# limit concurrency to 2 to not spam the server:
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)

async def get_lenght(session, url):
    async with sem, session.get(url) as resp:
        content = await resp.read()
        return url, len(content)

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = {get_lenght(session, url) for url in lst}
        for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            result = await task
            print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
('https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-File.png', 209659)
('https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Photo.png', 99739)
('https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Pic.png', 240212)
('https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/Harbor-Seal-PNG-Clipart.png', 13111524)
```